# Code shortcut for multiple joins

Tags: functional-style

does it exist a simple construct to express the following expression in a more succinct manner:

```
JoinAcross[ JoinAcross[ JoinAcross[v5sisPma5, v5sisPma6, "size"], v5sisAbTree, "size"], v5sisStatic, "size"]
```

I'm looking to something like `Fold[JoinAcross, v5sisPma5, {v5sisPma6, v5sisAbTree, v5sisStatic}]` with the additional parameter "size" to state the attribute in the equijoin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your `Fold` method if you use a pure function as the first argument,

```
Fold[
 JoinAcross[#1, #2, "size"] &, v5sisPma5, {v5sisPma6, v5sisAbTree, 
  v5sisStatic}]
(* JoinAcross[
 JoinAcross[JoinAcross[v5sisPma5, v5sisPma6, "size"], v5sisAbTree, 
  "size"], v5sisStatic, "size"] *)
```